# maven install command to deploy an artifact to maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

When i Use option of sts "**install or deploy an artifcator in eclipse**".it works properly but when i do it manually by using **mvn install** command and change the version in pom.xml.it deploys artifactory to local repository. but when i refered it in some other project its symbol is different from others.
[image]

in above image, **OES-ClientCore:24.0.9** is deployed using maven command and i ma refering it in some other project.

and also not working properly.so just tell me the difference of option of sts for "**install or deploy an artifcator in eclipse**" and manually using command **mvn install**

Comment: There is no difference. Additionally, _installing_ simply means to put the artifacts into the _local_ repository. And last: The M2E plugin is able to detect that a dependency already is an open project in the workspace, hence the different symbol.

Comment: Be aware of that for maven there is a difference. `mvn install` means installation in local repository only whereas `mvn deploy` means also to install an artifact into the remote repository as well.

Answer (score 0):

**mvn install** will install the artifact in your local maven repository.

Use **mvn deploy** to deploy it to a remote repository to share it with other developers and projects

**See also:**

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html